# Single AD user cannot login to iMac, but others can

Tags: active-directory, directory-utility

So, I thought this was the same issue I'd seen before with [the old Home folder name conflicting](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/1451099-imac-on-windows-domain-can-t-login-to-certain-single-user-account?page=1#entry-5521469), but it is not. The issue is the **the iMac "shakes" and refuses her password at login, but I am 100% certain it is correct AND she can login to her PC without issue** (and her AD account is not locked out from password attempts).
The iMac is running OS X El Capitan, 10.11.6. Windows DC is on Server 2008 (SBS 2008 to be exact).

The BIND from the Mac to our Active Directory (Windows) Domain seems fine since I can login as my AD user, but the owner of the Mac cannot login as herself, presumably because of something left over...? She is using a local account for now, but her Mapped Drives drop overnight, so we need to get her back to her AD account. So far I have tried:

- Unbind/rebind the Mac to the domain
- Checked to ensure all AD users can login to the Mac in System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Options
- Renamed her old local account AND the home folder and changed path
- Disable "Force local home directory on startup disk" under Directory Utility > User Experience
- Disable "Use UNC path from Active Directory to derive network home location" (also under Directory Utility > User Experience)

I can't find anything in the Keychain, but I don't know where else to look. What could be the issue here? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed, FINALLY!!! Deleting the local account with the similar name (but keeping Home drive on disk so I could migrate data) did the trick!** Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

could there be a local user with the same name?  not sure this should cause a stoppage since you checked the home folder.

if you use something like

```
dscacheutil -q user
```

do you see a local account with that user name?

Comment: Good God, 1294 lines of output from that command!! I'm wading thru it now via Notepad++.....negative, no local account with the same username. Anything else I can try?? Thank you, BTW!

Comment: can you grab the system.log at the time of the denying 'shake' login?  or watch it from ssh with something like tail -f /var/log/system.log  or maybe the security log

Comment: @SamAndrew81 Note that each account has two names, the "Full Name" (generally something like "Sam Andrew") and account name (more like "samandrew" or "sam.andrew" or something similar), and either one can conflict with either one. Also, it's hard to properly change a local account's account name; depending on exactly how you changed it, there might still be a conflict lurking somewhere. One (not necessarily foolproof) test for conflict is the command `id accountname` -- if it returns the same uid and/or groups for the local vs. AD accounts, there's a problem.

Comment: Thank you both. Yes, I have SSH access to the iMac via Putty. I will try the login and check system.log. Also, I will run a full TM backup and just completely delete the local account to rule it out...I'm think it must be an issue there as she used her name on the local account and it's in her AD account as well.

Comment: Well I'm stuck on both: 'id accountname' just returns 'no such user'  

...and when I'm SSH'd into the iMac via Putty and try '-f /var/log/system.log' it says command not found....?

Comment: One huge issue is she is our graphics person, so has nearly a **TB of local data**. Needless to say removing this and putting it back would be a HUGE headache, plus cause her a ton of downtime as we don't have another Mac....I need to just find the single user file that is causing the conflict between the local and AD accounts.

Comment: Sam, try "tail -f /var/log/system.log"  for a floating tail as entries occur

Comment: Thank you, @neuralstatic! I opened Putty and SSH'd into the iMac, ran the "tail" command and tried to login several times with her AD user and found this:  
'Oct 21 10:52:04 Mary-iMacWM authorizationhost[4946]: Get autologin pwd: failed to open /etc/kcpassword (2)'

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, the '/ect/kcpassword' file only pertains to auto-login..? If that's the case, it won't help as she doesn't have auto-login enabled on the iMac.

Comment: What about this script? https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3090068?tstart=0

Comment: wow that's an extensive looking script.  it just struck me, you did an `id username` and it came up with no such user?    if you run an `id youraccountname` it shows all the right info (from AD, not local)?  if it can look you up, it should be able to look her up, right?

Comment: If I open Terminal on the iMac and type id myADaccount or id herADaccount it is able to look us both up, yes. I can login with my AD account, but not hers.